# Pass data-id via modal to jQuery validate

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validate, bootstrap-modal

I am using jQuery Validate along with Bootstrap modal - I need to get the data-id of the original button clicked into the submit handler of validate so I can pass it via AJAX into the AJAX script.

Simplistically I have a link:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-modal" 
data-id="77" class="icon-plus-circle"></a>
```

Then I have my modal:

```
<div id="add-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add</h4>
            </div> 

            <form id="add_form" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">Start</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" name="start" id="add_start" value="" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 control-label">End</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <input type="text" name="end" id="add_end" value="" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>                      
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer ">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-p1" >
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and finally the JS:

```
        $("#add_form").validate({
            rules: {
                start: "required",
                end: "required"
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                var id=$(this).attr('data-id');
                var s=$('#add_start').val();
                var e=$('#add_end').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/add.php",
                    data: {start: s, end: e, eid: id},
                    success: function(){    
                        $('#add-modal').modal('hide');
                        $('#add_start').val('');
                        $('#add_end').val('');
                    }
                });
              return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

In the JS I either want to grab the ID of the click button or pass it into the modal itself as a hidden field so I can then serialize the form but I cannot figure out how to

I need to be able to pass the data-id value into the AJAX script so I can ensure the form values are applied against the right ID

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the `data-id` into the modal form as a `hidden` field, then this value will automatically become part of the query string when the form is serialized.  Otherwise, you can programmatically capture this value within your `submitHandler` no differently than your other field values.

Construct a `click` handler that will assign this value into a hidden field when it's clicked.

```
$('a.icon-plus-circle').on('click', function() {
    var buttonID = $(this).data('id'); // get value of data-id
    $('#hidden').val(buttonID);        // assign data-id to hidden field called #hidden
});
```

See:  https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2

Make sure `form` contains a hidden field with the same target as per above.

```
 <form id="add_form" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="" />
     ....
```

And capture/assign within `submitHandler`:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    var id = $('#hidden').val(); // get value of hidden field called #hidden
    ....
```